# How to put Å, Ä and Ö in a javascript array and then compare it with html text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, special-characters

I want to put Å, Ä and Ö. And then compare them using html text. For example text has these characters, and i want to compare my text using javascript array. I am trying to make javascript array using following line of code:

```
 var array = ['Å', 'Ä', 'Ö'];
```

i even tried Å Ä and Ö. These codes work for html but not javascript. How can i do that? thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Your code is producing an array, so what are you trying to do?

Comment: i am getting a string from html using $('#special_chr').text(); which is Å for example and then want to check if it exists in array.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of storing string literals in the array, store their unicode representations:

```
var myArray = ['\u197', '\u196', '\u214'];
```

I used [this website](http://www.mikezilla.com/exp0012.html) to convert your ASCII symbols to unicode.

Comment: i got this when tried to store your given unicode representations: [16:26:11.734] SyntaxError: malformed Unicode character escape sequence @ myweb.com/jquery_for_mainpage.js:6

Comment: @Piscean you may have to specify them as hex values instead of decimal (e.g. 197 -> C5)

Answer (score 1):

If your Javascript code is in a separate file than your HTML, you'll need to make sure that all of your files are using the same character encoding (e.g. utf-8). If you are using literals like this, you'll have to force your editor to use the correct encoding.

What editor are you using?