# How to check if a string contains Å, Ä or Ö character in java servlet?

Tags: java, string, servlets, special-characters

I am using java servlets. In my database some strings has characters Å, Ä and Ö. When i check those strings contains these special characters then its always false. How can i check if a string contains these special characters. I am using Eclipse. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting the strings out of your database correctly?  i.e. with the special characters?

Comment: Please post the relevants parts of your Servlet code so we can see what you've tried to so far and where that might be going wrong.

Comment: @JoeG i am using google app engine for data storage. in Logs i see ? instead of Å,Ä and Ö. But when i go to data storage and check stored strings then its showing Å,Ä and Ö correctly.

Comment: @Piscean, the application that you are using to view the Logs may not have support to show those characters thats why it is showing `?`.

Comment: Is this not the same question you asked yesterday? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12283369/how-to-put-and-in-a-javascript-array-and-then-compare-it-with-html-text

Comment: That was for javascript and i did not get any solution for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are extended ASCII chanracters.

```
byte[] data=new byte[1];
data[0]=(byte)197;  197 is for Å
String char1=new String(data,"ISO-8859-1");
```

You can create String "char1" like above and then Compare with Target String.

Code for Getting lookup :

```
for( int i=127;i < 256;i++)
        {
            byte[] char= new byte[1];
            char[0]= (byte)i;
            System.out.println("Data : "+char+","+
new String(char, "ISO-8859-1")+","+i); //'i' will give u code. 197 is for Å so on.
        }
```

See this table, Charset supported by Java SE 6 : Source : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html

```
US-ASCII    Seven-bit ASCII, a.k.a. ISO646-US, a.k.a. the Basic Latin block of the Unicode character set
ISO-8859-1      ISO Latin Alphabet No. 1, a.k.a. ISO-LATIN-1
UTF-8   Eight-bit UCS Transformation Format
UTF-16BE    Sixteen-bit UCS Transformation Format, big-endian byte order
UTF-16LE    Sixteen-bit UCS Transformation Format, little-endian byte order
UTF-16  Sixteen-bit UCS Transformation Format, byte order identified by an optional byte-order mark
```

Comment: How does this answer OPs question ?

Answer (score 0):

Encoding for input stream must be correct. Java strings are already encoded. Look that below example when reader uses `inputString` works very well. But in case of external input stream bytes needs be encoded to reader (and thus `java.lang.String`). Java uses default charset dependent on runtime platform when you don't pass nothing. When you know that charset is specific to application you should pass it as argument. Be careful because some charsets feed one byte (`ASCII`) and some feeds one or two bytes (`UTF8`) and some feeds two bytes (`UTF16`).

```
    // String charset = "UTF-8";
    // Reader inputReader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("xxxx"), charset);
    String inputString = "Å, Ä or Ö";
    StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(inputString);
    Reader reader = stringReader;
    int data = reader.read();
    while (data != -1) {
        char dataChar = (char) data;
        int codeChar = (int) data;
        System.out.println("char=" + dataChar + ", code=" + codeChar);
        data = reader.read();
    }
    String toReplace = "Å";
    String stringAfter = inputString.replace(toReplace, "B");
    System.out.println(stringAfter);

    // prints:

    char=Å, code=197
    char=,, code=44
    char= , code=32
    char=Ä, code=196
    char= , code=32
    char=o, code=111
    char=r, code=114
    char= , code=32
    char=Ö, code=214
    B, Ä or Ö
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **string.contains(s)** method.See sample;

```
  String x = "aaa Å bbb";
  if(x.contains("Å")){
      System.out.println("OK");
  }
```